# Set opacity to child div with css

Tags: css

I have a problem with inner div opacity. In my page two div boxes and I want set opacity to child div with css. Here is What I want in picture below.[image]

Comment: There's absolutely no problem with this you just have to write your css.

Comment: as i understand it's not such easy, maybe impossible using pure css. Because the "box-div" has no transparency and there is no option to mark a specific area as transparent. Maybe you can try a very large border for the inner div instead of the box-div...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use outline + rgba :
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/saviA - http://codepen.io/anon/full/saviA

```
html {
  background:turquoise
 url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100/abstract/10)
}

div {
  margin:5em;
  border:solid;
  overflow:hidden;
}
p {
  border:1px solid;
  margin:2em;
  padding:1em;
}
.opaclike {
  outline:2000px solid white;
  position:relative;
  z-index:-1;
  background:rgba(255,255,255,0.5)
}
```

```
<div>
  <p>text</p>
  <p class="opaclike">text</p>
  <p>text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: so you do not have to deal with opacity's 'after effects' on every single content of that box.

Comment: if you just apply what i discribed , you get it , i believe : http://jsfiddle.net/M8mnw/6/

Answer (score 0):

Here's the css that will make the inner div transparent:

```
#inner_box {
        zoom: 1;
        filter: alpha(opacity=70);
        opacity: 0.7;
    }
```

Have a look here for more info on the opacity rule: http://css-tricks.com/css-transparency-settings-for-all-broswers/

Comment: I don`t want set background image to inner_box. I want set transparent to page background. When I change zoom page inner_box background must not change position.